# using Apache's AsyncHttpClient in a storm bolt

Tags: java, apache-storm, asynchttpclient

I have a bolt that is making an API call (HTTP Get) for every tuple.
to avoid the need to wait for the response, I was looking to use the apache HttpAsyncClient.

after instantiating the client in the bolt's prepare method, the execute method constructs the URL from the tuple and calls sendAsyncGetRequest(url):

```
private void sendAsyncGetRequest(String url){

    httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(url), new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {

        @Override
        public void completed(HttpResponse response) {
            LOG.info("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine());
            LOG.debug(response.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Exception ex) {
            LOG.warn("Async http request failed!", ex);
        }

        @Override
        public void cancelled() {
            LOG.warn("Async http request canceled!");
        }
    });
}
```

the topology deploys but the Storm UI shows an error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request cannot be executed; I/O reactor status: STOPPED at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:12
```

Comment: I feel that there is not enough data to check this problem. How httpClient is instanciated? Can you post the full error stack?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work with no issues.
the key things to note are:

1. declare the client on the bolt class scope

   ```
   public class MyRichBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
       private CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpclient;
   ```
2. Instantiate and stat the client in the bolt's prepare method

   ```
   @Override
   public final void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
       try {
           // start the http client
           httpclient = HttpAsyncClients.createDefault();
           httpclient.start();
           // other initialization code ... 
       } catch (Throwable exception) {
       // handle errors
       }
   }
   ```
3. make the calls in the bolt's execute method

   ```
   @Override
   public final void execute(Tuple tuple) {
       // format the request url
       String url = ... 
       sendAsyncGetRequest(url);
   }


   private void sendAsyncGetRequest(String url){
       logger.debug("Async call to URL...");
       HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
       HttpAsyncRequestProducer producer = HttpAsyncMethods.create(request);
       AsyncCharConsumer<HttpResponse> consumer = new AsyncCharConsumer<HttpResponse>() {

           HttpResponse response;

           @Override
           protected void onResponseReceived(final HttpResponse response) {
           this.response = response;
           }

           @Override
           protected void onCharReceived(final CharBuffer buf, final IOControl ioctrl) throws IOException {
               // Do something useful
           }

           @Override
           protected void releaseResources() {
           }

           @Override
           protected HttpResponse buildResult(final HttpContext context) {
               return this.response;
           }
       };

       httpclient.execute(producer, consumer, new FutureCallback<HttpResponse>() {

           @Override
           public void completed(HttpResponse response) {
               // do something useful with the response
               logger.debug(response.toString());
           }

           @Override
           public void failed(Exception ex) {
               logger.warn("!!! Async http request failed!", ex);
           }

           @Override
           public void cancelled() {
               logger.warn("Async http request canceled!");
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Comment: An explanation of the root cause would be more helpful.  I.e., why does your prescribed solution work?

Answer (score 0):

Are you shutting down the client (client.close();) in your main flow before the callback can execute?

The error is saying that the IO path has already been closed. In general, instances of async clients should be re-used for repeated requests and destroyed only when "ALL" requests have been made, e.g. at application shutdown.